# Problem load offline opestreetmap in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm working in a map using leaflet and open street map. All work fine in online mode, but if I try to use local map(created by maperitive) i see only a grey windows.
That's my code:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('file:///C:/project/city/Berlin/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { }).addTo(map);
```

I suppose that there is a problem to load my local file.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work - javascript can't access `file://` URLs - by design.

Comment: Is not javascript but the tileLayer method that allow to access. I solved with a creation of a new osm and with this url: L.tileLayer('Berlin/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

Comment: Yes it is. Now you're using a relative URL not a file:// URL and that *is* allowed.